# Finding average for 2 students

Tags: c, variable-assignment

I am running a program to **calculate average** for 2 students. I am having trouble running this. For some reason it says **it cannot be found**. It's my first time using Visual Studio and I am not sure if my code is the problem or the program.

Please check if there's a mistake and let me know.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int firstGrade1;
    int sGrade1;
    int tGrade1;
    int fGrade1;

    int TotalGrade1 = (firstGrade1 + sGrade1 + tGrade1 + fGrade1);
    int AveGrade1 = (TotalGrade1 / 4);

    printf("Please enter Student 1 first grade:\n");
    scanf("%d", &firstGrade1);

    printf("Please enter Student 1 second grade:\n");
    scanf("%d", &sGrade1);

    printf("Please enter Student 1 third grade:\n");
    scanf("%d", &tGrade1);

    printf("Please enter Student 1 fourth grade:\n");
    scanf("%d", &fGrade1);

    int firstGrade2;
    int sGrade2;
    int tGrade2;
    int fGrade2;

    int TotalGrade2 = (firstGrade2 + sGrade2 + tGrade2 + fGrade2);
    int AveGrade2 = (TotalGrade2 / 4);

    printf("Please enter Student 2 first grade:\n");
    scanf("%d", &firstGrade2);

    printf("Please enter Student 2 second grade:\n");
    scanf("%d", &sGrade2);

    printf("Please enter Student 2 third grade:\n");
    scanf("%d", &tGrade2);

    printf("Please enter Student 2 fourth grade:\n");
    scanf("%d", &fGrade2);

    printf("1. Student 1 grades:");
    printf("%d", firstGrade1, sGrade1, tGrade1, fGrade1);
    printf(". Average is ");
    printf("%d\n", AveGrade1);

    printf("2. Student 2 grades:");
    printf("%d", firstGrade2, sGrade2, tGrade2, fGrade2);
    printf(". Average is ");
    printf("%d", AveGrade2);

    system("pause");

    return (0);

}
```

Comment: Order matters! You do your calculation before you have read the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This here

```
int TotalGrade1 = (firstGrade1 + sGrade1 + tGrade1 + fGrade1);
```

Doesn't tell it that `TotalGrade1` will just always be the value of those 4 variables added up. It assigns to `TotalGrade1` the sum of those variables' **current** values. Since those are uninitialized, that's undefined behavior. Move the calculation of `TotalGrade1` and `AveGrade1` to after you read in those values, and likewise for `TotalGrade2` and `AveGrade2`, of course.

Also, consider this print:

```
printf("%d", firstGrade1, sGrade1, tGrade1, fGrade1);
```

You are printing four `int`, why is there only one format specifier? The format string should be `"%d %d %d %d"`.

I suggest always paying attention to your compiler's warnings. Usually your compiler should warn you about incorrect `printf` format strings as well as using uninitialized variables.

---

On a side note, you have a lot of code duplication. What if you didn't have two students and four grades, but a hundred students with ten grades each? Imagine the amount of code, and the amount of work copy/pasting the code. Instead, try something like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    int Grade[2][4]; 
    int AveGrade[2];
    int TotalGrade[2];

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            printf("Please enter Student %d j. grade:\n", i + 1, j+1);
            scanf("%d", &Grade[i][j]);
        }

        TotalGrade[i] = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            TotalGrade[i] += Grade[i][j];
        AveGrade[i] = (TotalGrade[i] / 4);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        printf("%d. Student %d grades:", i+1, i+1);
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        printf("%d ", Grade[i][j]);
        printf(". Average is ");
        printf("%d\n", AveGrade[i]);
    }

    system("pause");
    return (0);
}
```